# Exodus 4:1 - Who were Moses' signs for?

Tags: exodus

According to the text of Exodus 3 & 4, were the signs listed in Exodus 4 given in response to Moses' concerns about Pharaoh, the elders of Israel, or both?

> Then Moses answered, "But behold, they will not believe me or listen to my voice, for they will say, 'The Lord did not appear to you.'"
>    Exodus 4:1 ESV
>   https://bible.com/bible/59/exo.4.1.ESV

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Moses is concerned that the people won't believe that the Lord appeared to him. This is clear from the answer that God gives with his instructions:

> *[First sign]* “so that they may believe that the Lord, **the God of their ancestors**, the God of Abraham, the God of Isaac, and the God of Jacob, has appeared to you ... *[second sign]*. If they will not believe you or heed the first sign, they may believe the second sign. If they will not believe even these two signs or heed you, ... *[third sign]*” (Exodus 4:5,8-9, NRSV)

So all three of the signs were meant to convince *the people*, not Pharaoh. And indeed, Moses performed the signs in front of *the people*, and they believed (4:30-31). Moses then appears before Pharaoh without performing any sign (5:1).

Performing signs for Pharaoh doesn't become a concern until later. Two of the signs for the nation (the snake and the blood) are later repeated for Pharaoh, but the original instruction in Exodus 4 was to perform the signs for the nation, and Moses doesn't perform the same signs before Pharaoh until he is instructed to do so (Exodus 7:9, 14-18).